# Boolean expression if false not working with ?? in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

```
<#function kafkaCacheBackupLoaderProfiles>
  <#assign profiles = []>
  <#if featureEnabled.createCacheLoader??>
    <#assign profiles = profiles + ["kafka-cache-loader"]>
  </#if>
  <#if featureEnabled.createBackupLoader!false>
    <#assign profiles = profiles + ["kafka-backup-loader"]>
  </#if>
<#return profiles?join(", ")>
```

for the input following inputs :

```
"featureEnabled": {
   "createCacheLoader": true
}
```

the code returns: `kafka-cache-loader`

```
"featureEnabled": {
            
}
```

the code returns : `<an empty profiles array>`

```
"featureEnabled": {
   "createCacheLoader": false
}
```

the code returns : `kafka-cache-loader`

1. it should return `<an empty profiles array>`  as createCacheLoader is false
2. I tried with  `<#if (featureEnabled.createCacheLoader)??>` but the result is same as shown above.

if we talk about the other expression:   `<#if featureEnabled.createBackupLoader!false>`
code is working as expected i.e incase `createBackupLoader` is `false or null` it does not print `kafka-backup-loader` . if `true` it prints `kafka-backup-loader`

I think I am missing some concept here.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, especially as you realized that you can use `!false`. The `featureEnabled.createCacheLoader??` expression just tells if `createCacheLoader` is existing and non-`null`, and it doesn't matter what the value is.

Comment: I see. so `featureEnabled.createCacheLoader??` only checks whether the element is there in `createCacheLoader`. hence, there is another check required after this which would compute based on the value `true/false` : 
  `<#if featureEnabled.createCacheLoader?? &&
 featureEnabled.createCacheLoader>`

Comment: You don't need another check. If you want it to be `false` in effect if it's not there, then write `featureEnabled.createCacheLoader!false`. (Also, you don't have to guess: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing)

Comment: I have summarized my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `featureEnabled.createCacheLoader??` expression just tells if `createCacheLoader` (inside `featureEnabled`, which must exist) is existing and non-null, and it doesn't matter what the value of it is. If you want it to be `false` in effect if it's not there, then write `featureEnabled.createCacheLoader!false`.

See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use it:

```html
<#if (featureEnabled.createCacheLoader)?has_content&&featureEnabled.createCacheLoader>
```

?has_content Determine whether the variable is empty

Comment: `?has_content` is only needed in more complicated cases where existing but empty strings and sequences (arrays, lists) can occur. As it's a boolean value, I think he really just needs to add a `!false` at the end, and that's all (but see my answer).